# How to Check if script is finished on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I'm writing for importing data from mysql to mongodb I'm new to node.js & mongoDb and my Question is how to check if everything's inserted to exit the script? It makes what it dows but I don't know to determine that the work is done.

```
var c = require('./config').development;
var mysql = require('mysql');
var mySqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : c.mysqlHost,
    port : c.mysqlPort,
    database : c.mysqlDatabase,
    user : c.mysqlUser,
    password : c.mysqlPassword
});
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, format = require('util').format;




var values = new Array("0", "100000", "200000", "300000", "400000");



MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/amazon', function(err, db) {

mySqlConnection.connect(function(err) {
            if (err !== null) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            values.forEach(function(limit) {
                        var sql = "SELECT id, ISO2, title, json_response FROM  amazon_product WHERE id>"+limit+" LIMIT 100000";
                        mySqlConnection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
                            rows.forEach(function(row) {
                                try {

                                    db.collection('amazon' , function(err, col){
                                        var obj = JSON.parse(row.json_response);
                                        obj.iso2 = row.ISO2;
                                        obj.mysqlId = row.id;
                                        //How can I check that everything's is inserted?
                                        col.insert(obj, function(){});

                                    });


                                } catch (e) {
                                    console.log('problem @id ' + row.id +' ' + e);

                                }

                            });
                        });
                        console.log("I'm on limit"+ limit);
                    });

        });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**lets consider this line:** `col.insert(obj, function(){});`

when method finished , the second argument function(callback) invoked.

**background:** node convention - any callback function should have first argument - error object. It is true for `insert` function also

```
col.insert(obj, function(err){
     if (err) console.log('Error happend');
     else console.log('every thing is fine');
});
```

Comment: Yes. this is called,  if 1 object is inserted to MongoDb but I'm inserting about 300k Objects.

Comment: it will be calling for each time function invoked, if 300k clients, will access this code, it will be called 300k times.

Comment: In order to insert object into mongodb you call insert. So if you call it N times, it will print it N times as a result it inserts N objects, or I don't understand you?

Comment: Yes I do. But my question is how to check if all objects are inserted.

Comment: If there is no string 'Error happen' in console at all.

Comment: Or count success attempts, and compare with rows number, or after first error, break the forEach function.